# Python TypeError: 'NoneType' does not support indexing on line 1

Tags: python, list, karel

I am using CodeHS Ultra Karel python, and I tried running this code:

```py
image = [ [ 1, 3, 3, 1],
          [ 3, 3, 3, 3],
          [ 1, 3, 3, 3],
          [ 3, 1, 1, 3] ]
colors = ["null","orange","blue","white"]

pos_x = 0
pos_y = 3

def move_plus(n=1):
    global pos_x
    global pos_y
    for i in range(n):
        if front_is_clear():
            if facing_north():
                move()
                pos_y += 1
            elif facing_south():
                move()
                pos_y -= 1
            elif facing_east():
                move()
                pos_x += 1
            else:
                move()
                pos_x -= 1

def paint_coordinates(x,y):
    paint(color[colors[image[y][x]]])

for i in range(4):
    paint_coordinates(pos_x,pos_y)
    move_plus()
```

This is in a 4x4 Karel world, with Karel starting in the top left. It should have Karel place a color that is listed at a coordinate and move, 4 times.
It gives me this error:
`TypeError: 'NoneType' does not support indexing on line 1`

Comment: Can you attach the full error stack?

Comment: This code is incomplete.  What is `facing_north()`?  What is `move()`?  What is `paint()`?

Comment: Where the code says `paint(color[image[y][x]])`, what do you expect this to mean? Specifically, what do you think `color` should refer to, and why? (Hint: does the code `colors = ["null","orange","blue","white"]` set a value for `color`? Look carefully.)

Comment: Is that the full code of the file being executed ? because it is mentionned line 1 and the line 1 you show is ok

Comment: Is `color` supposed to be `colors`? I suspect this is just a typo error.

Comment: PLEASE READ THE QUESTION I am using CodeHS' Ultra Karel python adition. These functions are all part of Ultra Karel, and not defined in the file.

Comment: @SurajShourie This is the only error.

Comment: @Barmar No, it should be `paint(color[colors[image[x][y]])`

Comment: If the library is hiding the traceback, it's going to be difficult to figure this out. We need to know which line of your code is causing the problem.

Comment: @JohnGordon "Karel" originally refers to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karel_(programming_language) , but nowadays the term (name, really) is applied with varying degrees of accuracy to a wide variety of systems and implementations. "CodeHS Ultra Karel python" seems to be some kind of web sandbox app which runs Python code within an environment where a bunch of things have been star-imported already.

Comment: please [edit] and share the EXACT and FULL stacktrace

Comment: "No, it should be `paint(color[colors[image[x][y]])`" - okay, but *the code that you showed to us does not say that*; so that is where the error presumably lies. (Although this attempt to fix it is missing a `]`.) We don't use the answer section here to explain typos. The comments here are only trying to be helpful (and make sure if there is a question **that is suitable to ask on Stack Overflow** underlying any of this); please carefully check these kinds of things **before** posting. Stack Overflow is not a [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) service.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I know, and I changed it, and it still gave the same error. That was just a typo.

Comment: What do you expect `color` to mean, and *why*? Where does that definition come from? Did you try to check what this code does, step by step? For example, does `image[x][y]` succeed by itself? Does it compute the result you expect it to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm discovering what is [*Karel*](https://compedu.stanford.edu/karel-reader/docs/python/en/chapter1.html).

I figured out that the `TypeError` was due to the way you're defining `image` in the [*sandbox*](https://codehs.com/explore/sandbox/karel).

Try to define it in a single line like below :

```
image = [[ 1, 3, 3, 1],[ 3, 3, 3, 3],[ 1, 3, 3, 3],[ 3, 1, 1, 3]]
```

Output :

[image]